# Remove Emoji Macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, emoji

I found a macro that will remove the emojis from Excel. My challenge is that I can't figure out how to get it to loop.  It only works on the first cell in the range. Ideally I'd like for it to be able to run through an entire active sheet or via a selected group of text. Any of the two would work fine.

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

```
Sub kleanIt()
Dim r As Range, v As Variant, L As Long
Dim CH As String, i As Long, N As Long

Set r = ActiveCell
v = r.Value
L = Len(v)

For i = L To 1 Step -1
    CH = Mid(v, i, 1)
    N = AscW(CH)
    If N < 1 Or N > 256 Then
        v = Replace(v, CH, "")
    End If
Next i

r.Value = v
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Sub kleanIt()
    Dim r As Range, v As Variant, L As Long
    Dim CH As String, i As Long, N As Long

    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        v = CStr(r.Value)
        If v <> "" Then
        L = Len(v)
            For i = L To 1 Step -1
                CH = Mid(v, i, 1)
                N = AscW(CH)
                If N < 1 Or N > 256 Then
                    v = Replace(v, CH, "")
                End If
            Next i
            r.Value = v
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```